# Dynamically inserting CSV data into dynamically created Tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to dynamically create tables and insert CSV data into them using sqlAlchemy.

given a set of CSV's:

```
FirstName, LastName
Mike, Myers
Ted,Stevens
```

and

```
name, city, district
Mike, london, waterloo
Ted, london, tower bridge
```

I have code that will create a table and the columns based on the CSV header:

```
import sqlalchemy
import csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    #get fieldnames from DictReader object and store in list
    headers = d_reader.fieldnames

metadata = MetaData()

b = Table(someGeneratedName, metadata,Column('row', Integer, primary_key=True),
*(Column(n, String) for n in headers))

engine = create_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

How do I insert the data into the table dynamically given the fact that I don't know what the table columns are?

Thanks

Comment: As you said, the columns are named after the headers. If you need to retrospectively find the columns after the table is created access the [`c`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.c) attribute of the table.

Answer (score 1):

While I might be biased as the author of the [SQLAthanor](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor) library, my recommendation would be to use SQLAthanor's `generate_model_from_csv()` function to auto-generate a SQLAlchemy declarative model based on your CSV file. SQLAthanor is a library designed to extend SQLAlchemy with support for robust serialization and de-serialization functionality.

The SQLAthanor `generate_model_from_csv()` function will read the CSV file and construct a SQLAthanor model (which inherits from SQLAlchemy's declarative model) based on what it finds. You can then create instances of that model class the records from the CSV file using SQLAthanor’s de-serialization functionality. For example:

```
import csv
from sqlathanor import generate_model_from_csv

MyCSVModel = generate_model_from_csv('test.csv',
                                     tablename = 'my_csv_table',
                                     primary_key = 'FirstName')

my_record_instances = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_records = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in csv_records:
        my_instance = MyCSVModel.new_from_csv(','.join(row), 
                                              delimiter = ',')
        my_record_instances.append(my_instance)
```

What the code above does is it first creates a declarative model class that supports serialization and de-serialization, then iterates through each row of the CSV file and creates an instance of the declarative model class. It then appends that instance to the list of record instances. Now you can interact with these instances the way you would normally interact with any SQLAlchemy model instance.

Here are some links to the relative documentation that you may find helpful:

- [SQLAthanor](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor) on Github
- [SQLAthanor Documentation](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#generating-sqlalchemy-tables-from-serialized-data) on ReadTheDocs
- [`generate_model_from_csv()`](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#generate-model-from-csv) documentation
- [`.new_from_csv()`](https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#new-from-csv) documentation

Hope this helps!